# Why wont nginx serve my static files off a subfolder?

Tags: nginx

Here is the configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  turfmetrics.com.au www.turfmetrics.com.au;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/turfmetrics.com.au.access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/turfmetrics.com.au.error.log;
    root /home/turfmetrics/production/;

    auth_basic "In development: Please log in";
    auth_basic_user_file /home/turfmetrics/htpasswords;

    location  /assets/ {
        alias  /home/turfmetrics/production/static_collected/assets/;
    }

    location  /static/ {
        alias  /home/turfmetrics/production/static_collected/;
    }

    location  /media/ {
        alias  /home/turfmetrics/production/media/;
    }

    location  = /favicon.ico {
        alias  /home/turfmetrics/production/media/favicon.ico;
    }

    location  = /robots.txt {
        alias  /home/turfmetrics/production/media/robots.txt;
    }

    location  / {
        proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_redirect        off;
        proxy_set_header      Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size  10m;
    }
    allow all;
}
```

If I access http://turfmetrics.com.au/static/assets/img/up.png I see the image but if I access  http://turfmetrics.com.au/assets/img/up.png I get a 404.

This file is just one example. I need the assets 'shortcut' because various javascript files use the assets path.

Comment: This question is better off on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) since it's more related to server administration then programming.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by making the location directives more explicit. If the assets, static or media files are not found, I don't want to punt the url anywhere else, I want it to fail. Thus I prefixed each of the static file lookups with the ^~ prefix thus:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  turfmetrics.com.au www.turfmetrics.com.au;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/turfmetrics.com.au.access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/turfmetrics.com.au.error.log;
    root /home/turfmetrics/production/;

    auth_basic "In development: Please log in";
    auth_basic_user_file /home/turfmetrics/htpasswords;

    location  ^~ /assets/ {
        alias  /home/turfmetrics/production/static_collected/assets/;
    }

    location  ^~ /static/ {
        alias  /home/turfmetrics/production/static_collected/;
    }

    location  ^~ /media/ {
        alias  /home/turfmetrics/production/media/;
    }

    location  = /favicon.ico {
        alias  /home/turfmetrics/production/media/favicon.ico;
    }

    location  = /robots.txt {
        alias  /home/turfmetrics/production/media/robots.txt;
    }

    location  / {
        proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_redirect        off;
        proxy_set_header      Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size  10m;
    }
    allow all;
}
```

This looks like it is better practice for the static file lookups anyway because I don't ever want them dropping through to the general processing (there are no valid urls that start with /static/ that do not correspond to files in the static_collected folder).

I'm not sure how static was working without this setting but it was. I'm guessing that the not found 404 for my assets were being generated by mezzanine under the `location /` directive.

For the Django developers out there; I added this to my urls.py in order to have the local `django-admin.py runserver` pick up the relevant files:

```
# Serve static media during development so things look right
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        '',
        (r'^{0}/(?P<path>.*)$'.format(settings.MEDIA_URL.strip('/')),
         'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        (r'^{0}/(?P<path>.*)$'.format(settings.ASSET_URL.strip('/')),
         'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.ASSET_ROOT}))
```